# Inlining of methods

Tags: java, классы, inline, final

В книге для подготовки к Java OCP экзамену прочитал следующее

> final classes encourage the inlining
>   of methods. With inlining, a method body can be expanded as part of the calling
>   code itself, thereby avoiding the overhead of making a function call. If the calls are to be resolved at runtime, they cannot be inlined.

Не понял, что конкретно имеется ввиду. Прочитал пару статей по этой теме - без толка.

Вопрос: Что есть инлайнинг методов? Мне надо понять суть.

Особенно непонятна вот данная цитата

> a method body can be expanded as part of the calling code itself,

ВНИМАНИЕ! Если данный вопрос является дубликатом, пожалуйста, вместо негативных оценок, просто ниже в комментах оставьте ссылку на оригинал, которая с вашей точки зрения, полностью отвечает на поставленный вопрос, если содержание ссылки даст нужные мне ответы - то данный вопрос сразу удалю.

Comment: Тут говорится об inline во время компиляций. Цепочка примерно такая: если класс final, то от него никто не может унаследоваться -> никто не может поменять методы класса, т.к. наследников нет -> если мы знаем, что объект класса в вызываемом коде точно является объектом final класса, то не нужен резолвинг метода в рантайме -> мы точно знаем, какой метод нужно вызвать на этапе компиляции. Раз так, то мы можем вставить тело метода прямиком в другой метод. Там есть еще куча уточнений, но идея такая.

Comment: @learp вот именно не представил как это делается " Раз так, то мы можем вставить тело метода прямиком в другой метод."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инлайнинг - это вставка тела метода в место его вызова. Что позволяет существенно увеличить скорость выполнения кода в некоторых случаях. Например до инлайнинга:

```
class Example {
    void someMethod(int i) {
        int v = i * i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    void anotherMethod() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            someMethod(i);
        }
    }
}
```

и после инлайнинга

```
class Example {
    void anotherMethod() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            int v = i * i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Только делает это JIT-компилятор, который работает не с java-кодом, а с машинным.

Comment: аааа. Только уточню: получается намного выгоднее нужные действия выполнить в рамках одного метода, нежели частями и в отдельных методах? Ну имеется ввиду с точки зрения производительности.

Comment: Да, это на порядки быстрее.

Comment: Хорошо.........